# overlapping versus shifting grid items

Tags: css, layout, css-grid, overlap

Before I start, I'd like to say that I spent some time looking into the topic I am about to describe, and I feel that this should not be marked as a duplicate, as I was unable to find a clearly outlined solution to my question...
Which is, how does CSS grid determine when grid items that exist inside of a grid container will be superimposed over each other in the layout, or whether they will shift each other in the layout, in instances when their allocated grid-areas logically overlap... that is, when they have been allocated some of the same grid area.

I was working my way through a popular CSS Grid learning tool recently, a game called
https://cssgridgarden.com/
and I came to a challenge that demonstrates that grid items can be made to overlap. To quote the game: "You can overlap them without any trouble".
This was fine. I carried on... and no apparent problem.
Here are some screenshots of the game:
[screenshot of CSS Garden game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcxwr.png)
[screenshot of CSS Garden game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0W6ln.png)

I was then, a little later working through yet another popular learning tool, Scrimba that is.
And in one of their courses 'Learn CSS Grid', there was some code that I started to experiment with, I copied the code and created my own codepen with it.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">HEADER</div>
  <div class="menu">MENU</div>
  <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
  <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.container {
    border: 5px dotted red;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 3px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 40px 200px 40px; }
.container > * {
  border: 2px solid green; }
.header {
    grid-column: 2 / -1; }
.menu {
    grid-row: 1 / -1; }
.content {
    grid-column: 2 / -1; }
.footer {
    grid-column: 1 / -1; }
```

This is the output on codepens simulated browser:
[Codepen output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLfrK.png)
You can see here that the footer area has been pushed out from the grid at the bottom.
It exists outside of the grid, beyond the .menu item.
I also tried added the following rule to the .footer class `grid-row: 2 / -1;` and this didn't change things in the layout visually at all.

I also checked back with a codepen that I had created previously, which had behaved, seemingly contrary to this, in which the grid items did indeed overlap each other, and appear superimposed, and layered across each other.
Here is the code for this pen...

HTML:

```
<div class="board">
  <div class="water">content</div>
  <div class="soil">content</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.board {
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:
    20% 20% 20% 20% 20%;
  grid-template-rows:
    20% 20% 20% 20% 20%;
}
.water {
  grid-row: 2 / 5;
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
  background-color:rgba(10,10,250,.5);
}
.soil {
  grid-row: 3 / 3;
  grid-column: 2 / 6;
  background-color:rgba(100,50,5,.5);
}
```

And here's how it looked in the codepen browser:
[Codepen output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGKDr.png)

The grid items in the latter example clearly overlap...
So I was obviously confused when I was experimenting with the first example and saw that the explicit placement of some grid items, seemed to "bump" other items around, and even go so far as to "bump" them off the grid altogether.

Thanks for reading all. I would greatly appreciate if anyone can shed some light on this topic for me.
Thank you.

Update: As requested, I have provided an example of my issue, only this time I have explicitly set the grid positions on all of the grid items.
You will see that I have used -1 on many of the items to make them run to the edge of the grid, which I was expecting would make them overlap with the "menu" area... and this hasn't happened... again, thanks for reading.

Here's is the updated codepen:
HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">HEADER does not overlap with menu</div>
  <div class="menu">MENU</div>
  <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
  <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 95vw;
    height: 50vh;
    border: 5px dotted red;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 3px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr) }
.container > * {
  border: 2px solid green; }
.header {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row: 1 / 2}
.menu {
    grid-row: 1 / -1;
    grid-column: 4 / -1;}
.content {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row: 2 / 5}
.footer {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row: 5 / -1;}
```

And the output to the codepen browser:[codepen browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1KVW.png)

Comment: Extra items will be created if there is no room for something (note the dotted red border encompasses the footer). Could you add a runnable snippet to your question which shows no overlapping even when you explicitly place the footer in a row? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hey. I've updated my code with the grid-items being explicity. And I'm still not getting the overlap effect that I was expecting. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I made a workable code snippet for you and made the background of the header pink so you can see it overlaps. If you want to position the header over the menu you have to change the Z-index of the header to for instance 5 (so it is higher then the menu).

```
.header {
        background-color: pink;
        grid-column: 1 / -1;
        grid-row: 1 / 2;
        z-index: 5;

      }
```

More on z-index: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

I hope this solves your problem. Otherwise let me know.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<style>
  .container {
    width: 95vw;
    height: 50vh;
    border: 5px dotted red;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 3px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr)
  }
  
  .container>* {
    border: 2px solid green;
  }
  
  .header {
    background-color: pink;
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
  }
  
  .menu {
    grid-row: 1 / -1;
    grid-column: 4 / -1;
  }
  
  .content {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row: 2 / 5
  }
  
  .footer {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row: 5 / -1;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">HEADER does not overlap with menu</div>
    <div class="menu">MENU</div>
    <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
    <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes this works. Thank you. I was just looking at my previous code too funnily enough.
Both the last example from my post, and your suggestion are working well.
Thanks. Grid items overlapping happily.

Comment: Liked your answer btw... though, I'm still a fairly new user so this may not be apparent on the thread. Thank you.